# Masking an ImageCollection using another Image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking

I want to mask all the layers in an `ImageCollection` (in the present case *MOD44B*) using the landcover (*Globcover*) values from another `Image`.

```
var MOD44B = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD44B"),
    Globcover = ee.Image("ESA/GLOBCOVER_L4_200901_200912_V2_3"),
    visualization = {"bands":["Percent_Tree_Cover"],"min":0,"max":100,"palette":["bbe029","0a9501","074b03"]};

var MOD44B = MOD44B.filterDate('2000-01-01', '2019-12-31')
var MOD44B = MOD44B.select('Percent_Tree_Cover')

var Globcover = Globcover.select('landcover')
var Globcover = Globcover.lte(30).or(Globcover.gte(190)).rename('Class');
print(Globcover)
Map.addLayer(Globcover)

//MOD44B = MOD44B.map(Globcover.eq(1)); //<------ This line is not working.
Map.addLayer(MOD44B, visualization, 'TC')
```

I want to mask all the white regions from *Globcover* (`Image`) in *MOD44B* (`Imagecollection`).
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ImageCollection.map` takes a *function* to apply to each image in the collection. Give it a function which applies the mask:

```js
MOD44B = MOD44B.map(function (image) {
  return image.updateMask(Globcover);
});
```

I also removed `.eq(1)` because it was unnecessary — the image you called `Globcover` is already binary since it came from `.or()`.

Comment: The code worked perfectly. Thanks, @Kevin.